# How to scale content for displays keeping the ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a Comic publishing site. While designing the comic reader page I am so stuck at UX. I think I have to display comics by reader's display size.

Lately I saw the page of Comic for Champion called Poppy from League of legends you can check it [**here**](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/site/poppy-comic/). This page gave me so much inspiration. As you can see this page is responsive and animated by using CSS `transform: scale()`. I want to use this but can't find any tutorial on google. Can you guys show me some example for how to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated:*** This [**JS Fiddle**-*Updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/rx7j0vLf/) simulates that comic page in the example but in simpler way.

The javascript code contains comments lines to explain how it works, for the CSS most of the code lines are self-explained, most importantly these lines for the `#outer` div to mimic the transition on window re-size:

```
transform: scale(1, 1);
transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

and inside the media query

```
transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

and for all `.inner` divs we scale them up using `.scaleUp` class while they're transparent, and then on each click we add `.scaleDown` class to the corresponding item to transitionally scale it back to its original size as well as setting its `opacity` to `1`:

```
.scaleUp {
    transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
}
.scaleDown {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

It is also important that in javascript that the value of `xWidth` should be `1px` higher than the break-point defined in the CSS media query.

---

**Full Code:**

```js
var iDivs = $('#outer .inner'),
    iLeftDivs = $('.left .inner'),
    iRightDivs = $('.right inner'),
    outer = $('#outer'),
    lefts = $('.left'),
    xWidth = 651, i = 0, winW, isHeightChanged = false;
 
// Scaling all .inner divs up while opacity 0
iDivs.addClass('scaleUp');
control();

// On Click, call update(), and on resize call control() 
$(window).on('click', update);

$(window).on('resize', control);

// This will control showing or hiding the left column divs -
// If the window width is bigger than the break point width - 
// show default behaivor, otherwise if we still showing the -
// left divs then it shows the left divs, if we already -
// finished left and showing right divs, it shows right instead -
// With a little bug fix for .left margin-top when resizing before -
// reachign the point where showing .right divs;
function control(){
    winW = $(window).width();
    if(winW < xWidth){
        if(i > iLeftDivs.length ){
            lefts.css({'margin-top':'0'}).hide();
        }else{
            lefts.css({'margin-top':'10px'}).show();
        }
        if(!isHeightChanged){
            isHeightChanged = true;
        }else{
            if(isHeightChanged){
                isHeightChanged = false;
            }
        }
    }else{
        lefts.css({'margin-top':'0'}).show();
    }
}


function update(){
    winW = $(window).width();
    if(winW < xWidth){
        // If we already finished showing the divs on left and now -
        // showing the right divs, we hide the .left div.
        if(i >= iLeftDivs.length){
            $('.left').hide();
        }
        $(iDivs[i]).addClass('scaleDown');
        i++;
    }else{
        // As long as we haven't finished showing all divs, we add the -
        // the scaling down class to show them and increase the counter.
        if(i < iDivs.length){
            $(iDivs[i]).addClass('scaleDown');
            i++;
        }else{
            //Here you should write the code that populate the next page's images
        }
    }
}
```

```css
html, body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:orange;
}
#outer {
  min-width:450px;
  width: 90vw;
  max-width:800px;
  padding: 1vh 1vw;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:5px;
  /* We scale it to original size with transition effect using below lines */
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
/* clear fix because of the float */
#outer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.inner {
  background-color: #090;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  color:white;
  min-height: 19vh;
  margin:5px;
  opacity:0;
  padding:3px;
}
.left, .right{
  width: calc(51% - 2vw);
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
.right{
  float:right;
}

#in2 { background-color: navy; }
#in3 { background-color: maroon; }
#in4 { background-color: #444; }
#in5 { background-color: brown; }
#in6 { background-color: purple; }

/* initially scale all .inner divs up while they're transparent */
.scaleUp {
  transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
}
/* on each click we scale down to original size, set opacity to 1 with transition */
.scaleDown {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px){
  #outer{
    width: 455px;
    /* We scale it up just a bit to add the required effect using below lines */
    transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .left, .right{
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
    margin:0 auto;
    float:none;
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <div class="left">

    <div class="inner" id="in1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae eius.
    </div>
    <div class="inner" id="in2">
      Molestias quisquam iusto alias asperiores est non explicabo esse, nisi mollitia. Accusamus nisi, numquam provident eaque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure autem maxime accusantium explicabo, ducimus nam laborum praesentium
      assumenda deserunt! Placeat eaque distinctio deserunt sapiente minima aliquam et quae veritatis possimus?
    </div>
    <div class="inner" id="in3">
      Nostrum quae cum eius fugiat, repudiandae consectetur, nulla maxime quasi dolor voluptates voluptatem.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="inner" id="in4">
      Molestias quisquam iusto alias asperiores est non explicabo esse, nisi mollitia. Accusamus nisi, numquam provident eaque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure autem maxime accusantium explicabo, ducimus nam laborum praesentium
      assumenda deserunt! Placeat eaque distinctio deserunt sapiente minima aliquam et quae veritatis possimus?
    </div>
    <div class="inner" id="in5">
      Nostrum quae cum eius fugiat, repudiandae consectetur, nulla maxime quasi dolor voluptates voluptatem.
    </div>
     <div class="inner" id="in6">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae eius.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir thank you very much! This is the second thing I want! But also I want the responsiveness. If you resize your browser in League of legends' comic page you will see the content of comic is resize with animate. How can I do that?

Comment: I've already updated the answer, try to resize the result panel in the fiddle, the only thing remaining now is when the view width is smaller than let's some certain width instead of showing 2 pages it shows 1 page only, and I am working on it

Comment: This didn't finish yet, just give me some more time it is almost done the way you want it.

Comment: @AkainuLionheart, check the final answer now, it is complet

Comment: Oh! This looks much more great! I am applying now thank you @Mi-Creativity

Comment: You welcome @AkainuLionheart, I'm glad it helped